# What is the Applicative's pure for Data Two a b = Two a b

Tags: haskell

Given this type:

```
data Two a b = Two a b deriving (Eq, Show)
```

What would be the Applicative definition. I'm not able to get the `pure` right without adding a constraint on `a` like for example `Num a`

```
instance (Num a, Monoid a) => Applicative (Two a) where
  pure b = Two 1 b
  Two f f' <*> Two a b = Two a (f' b)
```

Comment: You already have a `Monoid a` constraint, so you should use `mappend` and `mempty`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have it without a constraint. You need to do something about `a` and to be able to you need to have operations for that type, which you can get two ways: either use a specific type (e.g., `Int`, or an abstract one, requiring a typeclass instance).

The most general constraint that comes to mind in such a case is `Monoid`, which renders your instance the same as for the 2-element tuple:

```
instance Monoid a => Applicative ((,) a) where
    pure x = (mempty, x)
    (u, f) <*> (v, x) = (u `mappend` v, f x)
```

Comment: `Monoid` isn't just convenient btw, its laws are also exactly what you need to get a law-abiding `Applicative` "for free". To see what I mean, try to prove the `Applicative` laws for `((,) a)` without left- and right-identity of `mempty` or associativity of `mappend`.

Comment: mempty was probably my missing piece, so I end up having `pure b = Two mempty b`. Thanks!

Comment: Due to Haskell's lazy evaluation, you technically *can* have it without a constraint, though you probably don't *want* to. `pure x = Two undefined x`